Add NumberStyles to DataRow.ItemArray parser
I'm working on putting a CSV file into a DataTable. The order of the columns in the CSV can change so I have a utility that maps columns to different object values as well as their Type
There is an "Amount" column that is a Decimal. Negative numbers are masked with parentheses (e.g. "(#.##)" instead of "-#.##"). Is there a way to add the NumberStyles.AllowParentheses to the DataRow.ItemArray Decimal parser?
I like the efficiency of DataRow.ItemArray = string[] and would prefer to not go through and manually parse the decimal values.
public class BatchTable : DataTable
{
...

    // INSIDE CONSTRUCTOR...

    // This is the header row
    foreach (string colName in csvParser.ReadFields())
    {
        // If the field has been mapped, then we know the datatype for the table
        if (CCImportMap.ImportMappings.TryGetValue(colName, out ImportMapping mapping))
        {
            this.Columns.Add(colName, mapping.ColumnDataType);                    
        }
        else
        {
            this.Columns.Add(colName);
        }                
    }

    // Now add the rest of the batch
    while (!csvParser.EndOfData)
    {
        // Read current line fields, pointer moves to the next line.
        string[] fields = csvParser.ReadFields();
        DataRow dr = this.NewRow();
        dr.ItemArray = fields; // ERR: Can't parse "(#.##)" as a negative decimal value
        this.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}

